# Unexpected behaviour depicted by ceil function

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
long X;
std::cin >> X;
long f = ceil(X);
std::cout << f;
}
```

I'm using the gcc compiler(version 5.4.0) and instead of rounding up(what ceil is supposed to do , it rounds down the answer)
Input:
10.42
Output:
10(11 expected)

Comment: Debugging tip: look at the value of `X` before concluding that `ceil(X)` is giving the wrong result.

Answer (score 3):

The `long` data type is integral; it cannot store fractional components.  The line `std::cin >> X` is truncating the fractional part before `ceil` ever sees the value.  That is, when you invoke `ceil` you are passing it 10, not 10.42.

Change `long X;` to `double X;` (or `float X;`).

---

And before you use floating point types (`float` and `double`) please read [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).